# Getting values of dynamically generated Entry fields using Tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter

I've got a list of attributes such as cost, price, isObsolete etc. which I would like to dynamically generate as a label with an Entry field underneath, for the user to insert the correct value into.

It seems the best way to do this is to store the attributes against the values in a dictionary, and update this dictionary whenever the Entry field is updated.

I've tried used the trace_variable function on the StringVar assigned to my entry field, but it doesn't seem to when I type into the field (as a test) or when I run a function on the class to get the keys and values of the dictionary:

```
from Tkinter import *
import ttk

t = ['cost','price','isObsolete']

root = Tk()

rowAcc = 1
colAcc = 0

d = {}

for item in t:
    newValue = StringVar()

    def callback(*args):
        print args[0] + " variable changed to " + newValue.get()
        d[item] = newValue.get()

    newValue.trace_variable("w", callback)

    ttk.Label(root, text=item).grid(column=colAcc, row=rowAcc, sticky=(N, W))

    reqEntry = ttk.Entry(root, textvariable=newValue, width=19)
    reqEntry.grid(column=colAcc, row=rowAcc + 1, sticky=(N, W), pady=3, padx=1)

    colAcc += 1

def printDict():
    for key in d:
        print key, d[key]

root.mainloop()
```

Is there a way of tweaking this to achieve my result, or is there a better solution altogether to getting the values of dynamically generated entry fields?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Save `StringVar` in array

```
from Tkinter import *

master = Tk()

frame = Frame(master)
frame.pack()

s_vars = []

for i in range(5):
    s_vars.append( StringVar() )

    def onChange(a ,b, c, s_var):
        print a, "changed to", s_var.get()

    s_vars[i].trace('w', lambda a, b, c, x=i: onChange(a, b, c, s_vars[x]) )

    en = Entry(frame, textvariable=s_vars[i])
    en.pack()

    s_vars[i].set( str(i) )

mainloop()
```