# Is there a way to dynamically create Entry's and add their input to a list | Tkinter

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter, tkinter-entry

First time asking a question on here, but I was trying to create a program where Entry is dynamically created but I don't know how to take the text from the Entry and put it into a list.

I was looking at the question here: [Getting values of dynamically generated Entry fields using Tkinter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24282331/getting-values-of-dynamically-generated-entry-fields-using-tkinter), but I couldn't figure out how to have the code work in my particular case and things have probably changed in the past five years.

Any feedback would be appreciated.

Example:

```py
tk.Entry(TAB1, textvariable=username[i])
tk.Entry(TAB1, textvariable=username[i])
```

The first one would get a value like 'username1' and the second one would get 'username2' and so on for the rest of the dynamically added Entry's.

If there is a smarter way of doing this or you want me to show all my code, please let me know!

EDIT:
Here is my code for adding the buttons

```py
nextRow = 4

usernames = []

def addInput():
    global nextRow

    entry = tk.Entry(TAB1)
    entry.grid(row=nextRow, column=0, sticky='WE', padx=10, pady=2)
    ent2 = tk.Entry(TAB1).grid(row=nextRow, column=1, sticky='WE', padx=10, pady=2)
    ent3 = tk.Entry(TAB1).grid(row=nextRow, column=2, sticky='WE', padx=10, pady=2)

    nextRow += 1

    usernames.append(entry.get())
```

I also have a button that uses `addInput()` when the user would like to add a new row of three `tk.Entry`

```py
tk.Button(TAB1, text='Add', command=addInput, font=("Consolas", 12), width = 8).grid(row=1, column=1, sticky='W')
```

At this point I am unsure how to add the entry and keep track of its value.

Comment: _"things have probably changed in the past five years."_ - not in this case. Tkinter changes _very_ slowly, and takes backwards compatibility _very_ seriously.

Answer (score 0):

Generally speaking you don't need to use a textvariable at all. Just keep the entries in a list, and the refer to the list to get the values. The use of `textvariable` is ok, but it the way most people use it it just adds overhead without providing any real value.

```
entries = []
for i in range(10):
    entry = tk.Entry(TAB1)
...
for i in range(10):
    print(f"Entry {i} has value {entries[i].get()}")
```

If you really want to use a `textvariable`, the same technique still applies but you save the variable rather than the entry.

```
vars = []
for i in range(10):
    var = tk.StringVar()
    vars.append(var)
    entry = tk.Entry(Tab1, textvariable=var)
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer, as I am new to python and Tkinter I am unclear how to make this code work for me. I am going to edit and add more information to my question so hopefully, I can figure out a way to make it work in my scenario